# Как изменить максимальный размер загружаемого файла в ASP.Net Boilerplate шаблоне?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

Я использую шаблон [ASP.Net Boilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates) (ASP.Net Core 2.x, MVC, jQuery) версии 4.2.0. Когда я пытаюсь загрузить файл с помощью AJAX в контроллер, я получаю ошибку [HTTP 404.13](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/#overview), которая указывает на превышение максимального размера файла. Там-же, на странице официальной документации, приведены [настройки конфигурации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/#configuration), но редактирование [web.config](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/734394a61cc3b8659cb3c02691accbfd7aa81899/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/web.config) всё равно не помогает.

Как увеличить максимальный размер загружаемого файла в ABP Zero Core шаблоне?

```
// Пробовал редактировать следующие файлы так
// *.Web.Host\Startup\Program.cs 
// *.Web.Mvc\Startup\Program.cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) {
    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel(options => { 
            // безрезультатно...
            options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 1024 * 1024 * 1024; 
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ABP Zero Core шаблон не содержит каких-либо настроек ограничивающих размер загружаемого файла. Это означает, что значения используются по-умолчанию. Для изменения максимального размера загружаемого файла необходимо изменить два файла: [Web.Mvc\Startup\Startup.cs](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/bb9d5aab6e5047d6d22d49831b473c0b3329b499/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/Startup/Startup.cs) и [Web.Mvc\web.config](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/734394a61cc3b8659cb3c02691accbfd7aa81899/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/web.config).
`web.config` использует IIS и по умолчанию в нём нет узла `requestFiltering`, который нужно добавить и настроить. В `Startup.cs` необходимо настроить опции форм:

**`*.Web.Mvc\Startup\Startup.cs`**

```
namespace ProcimMS.Web.Startup {
    public class Startup {

        // ...

        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

            services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => {
                // либо используйте нужное значение в байтах
                x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**`*.Web.Mvc\web.config`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/ -->
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- 
        https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/

        uint maxAllowedContentLength
        Задает максимальную длину содержимого в запросе в байтах.
        Значение по умолчанию - 30000000, что составляет приблизительно 28,6 МБ.

        uint maxQueryString
        Задает максимальную длину строки запроса в байтах.
        Значение по умолчанию: 2048.

        uint maxUrl
        Задает максимальную длину URL в байтах.
        Значение по умолчанию: 4096.
        -->
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <!-- другие настройки... -->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Если я допустил какие-либо неточности или ошибки, то дайте мне об этом знать в комментариях.

---

#### Ссылки по теме

- [Конфигурация ограничений запросов в IIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/#configuration)
- [Класс FormOptions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.formoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.1)
- [Связанный вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53829487)